# handwriting recognition with simple training

Tags: ocr, handwriting

I've been reading (and trying) OCR programs suggested in previous answers but I'm still without a clear answer to my problem.

I need to recognize handwritten English text. The text would be multiple lines but each line is only one or two words length. The text is from a different person at  time. I could ask that person to provide a training file (e.g. with the alphabet and 0-9 numbers) but I cannot really ask for a much more complicated training than this.

I need to integrate the recognition as part of another (Java) application but the solution doesn't need to be Java. I can just execute it from Java and get the results from a text file.

Any recommendations?

I've already tested Tesseract (bad results without training and training looks quite complex). Java OCR looked like the perfect solution (simple training, open source and Java) but it doesn't work well even with their own examples (anybody has had a better experiencie?). GOCR does not seem very active.

Of course I prefer free solutions but this is not a MUST (though the problem I see with a commercial option is that I must be able to integrate it in my own app which will be offered as SaaS)

Comment: There is a difference between Handwritten and so called Handprinted recognition. The difference is mostly are charecters connected to each other or not. Not connected characters filled by hand are widely used in forms recognition, and this technology is called ICR (as opposed to OCR and HWR).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience  ABBYY is one of the best for handwriting recognition, even without training.  (It's possibly one of the most expensive too, though...)  They have an SDK for Java.

http://www.abbyy.com

With a free trial, it's definately worth a look!

Comment: other people seem to disagree (about ABBYY´s strength on handwriting recognition) but of course I´ll give it a try. What other options have you tried?

Comment: ABBYY does not do handwriting recognition at all, but it does handprinted recognition, so called ICR. IT is widely used in forms processing. Based on the question - recognition of numbers, ICR is what is actually needed there.

Comment: Well the question is abou recognition of numbers AND letters. I guess I could ask the users to make sure characters are separated and then I'd be able to use ICR. ¿Recommendations for ICR open source or free engines?

Comment: Tried it. Not good it all. Their website interface needs work. It just gives me a copy of what I already uploaded.

Comment: The answer relates to the functionality of their Abbyy FineReader softweare, not the usability of their website.

Answer (score 0):

I am on the lookout for a handwritten text recognition software. So far the only one giving better results than even abby 11 has been SimpleOCR using the same text for both, which is a freeware for ocr but a 14 day trial for HCR!

Answer (score 0):

I know I am answering after nearly 6 years. But if anyone's still looking, try using tensorflow. Their website has a simple example for handwritten digit recognition(MNIST). You can use this example and implement it for handwritten alphabet recognition (you need training data for this, I used NIST special Database 19 to get this data).

Comment: tensorflow does not recognize real handwritten text out of the box. It can only parse print letters (which is basically what MNIST is). Real handwriting is much more difficult because you have to take into account cursive, ligatures, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend [OCR4all](https://www.ocr4all.org/). The installation requires some tech skills, for sure, but it is completely free and open-source. Also, it has an ever-growing community (mostly academics) contributing training data and reusable models for both print and manuscript sources.